key-vault --> Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403
I'm using terraform to trying to deploy event-hubs to Azure, but I always get this error when I do terraform plan:
│ Error: making Read request on Azure KeyVault Secret evnhs-d-test-01-tp-test-01-tp-seli: keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=xxx;oid=xxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/6f/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'kv-d-test-01-tp;location=westeurope'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}
│ 
│   with module.eventhub_02.azurerm_key_vault_secret.event_hub_namespace_secrets_send_listen,
│   on .terraform/modules/eventhub/event-hub/main.tf line 235, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "event_hub_namespace_secrets_send_listen":
│  235: resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "event_hub_namespace_secrets_send_listen" {
│ 

I have 2 repositories, one with the modules and another where I deploy the Azure infrastructure.
I have a module called events-hub with this main.tf:
# Event Hub namespace to store Event Hubs
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "event_hub_namespace" {
  name                 = format("evnhs-%s", var.event_hub_namespace_name)
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  sku                  = var.event_hub_namespace_sku
  capacity             = var.event_hub_namespace_capacity
  auto_inflate_enabled = false

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [auto_inflate_enabled]
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

...

}

# Defines a namespace-level authorization rule for send and listen operations.
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule" "evhns_auth_rule" {
  name                = format("send-list-%s", var.event_hub_namespace_name)
  namespace_name      = format("evhns-%s", var.event_hub_namespace_name)
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  listen     = true
  send       = true
  manage     = false
  depends_on = [azurerm_eventhub_namespace.event_hub_namespace]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "event_hub_namespace_secrets_send_listen" {
  name         = format("%s-seli", azurerm_eventhub_namespace.event_hub_namespace.name)
  value        = azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule.evhns_auth_rule.primary_connection_string
  key_vault_id = var.keyvault_id

  depends_on = [azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule.evhns_auth_rule]
}

In my other repository I have a key-vaul.tf that has the necessary permissions for deployment and another file called event-hub.tf:

module "eventhub" {
  source = "git::git@github.com:..."

  keyvault_id = module.kv_data_02.vault_id

  event_hub_namespace_name     = format("%s-test-01-tp", var.environment)
  event_hub_namespace_sku      = "Standard"
  event_hub_namespace_capacity = "5"
  location                     = var.default_location
  resource_group_name          = var.default_resource_group
  tags                         = merge(var.tags, local.eventhub_tags)

  event_hubs_with_capture = [
    {
      resource_group_name = var.default_resource_group
      eventhub_name       = "raw-logsin"
      ...
      archive_name_format = "{Namespace}/{EventHub}/captured/{Year}_{Month}_{Day}_{Hour}_{Minute}_{Second}_{PartitionId}"
    },
  ]

  event_hubs_without_capture = []

  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.resource_id
}




I have owner permission on my key vault and I think it's fine...I don't understand why this name is like that: evnhs-d-test-01-tp-test-01-tp-seli shouldn't it be like this?evnhs-d-test-01-tp-seli? How can I correct the error I have above?
I know this is something simple, and that it must be in front of my eyes, but I'm not seeing it
I've already tried to see if there was a problem with event_hub_namespace_name, if it was repeating somewhere, I confirmed that my key vault is ok with the necessary permissions...

My key-vault.tf it's something like this:
module "kv_data_01" {

  source               = "git::git@github.com:..."
  resource_group_name  = var.default_resource_group
  kv_name              = format("kv-%s-test-data-01-tp", var.environment) 
  location             = var.default_location
  environment          = var.environment
  key_vault_secrets    = []
  kv_tenant_id         = var.sp_tenantid
  kv_sku_name          = "standard"
  tags                 = merge(local.kv_test_data_tags, var.tags)

   access_policies_list = [
    {
      object_id : var.kv_test_data_01_default_access[var.environment],
      key_permissions         = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Update"],
      secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List", "Purge", "Set", "Delete"],
      storage_permissions     = ["Get", "List"],
      certificate_permissions = ["Backup", "Create", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Import", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Update"]
    }
    ,
    {
      object_id : var.adsg-iot-team, 
      key_permissions         = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Update"],
      secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List", "Purge", "Set", "Delete"],
      storage_permissions     = ["Get", "List"],
      certificate_permissions = ["Backup", "Create", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Import", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Update"]
    }
    ,
    {
      object_id : var.sp_objid # service principal that deploys objects
      key_permissions         = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Update"],
      secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List", "Purge", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Restore"],
      storage_permissions     = ["Get", "List"],
      certificate_permissions = ["Backup", "Create", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Import", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Update"]
    }
    ,
    {
      object_id : var.adsg-owners,
      key_permissions         = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Update"],
      secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List", "Purge", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Restore"],
      storage_permissions     = ["Get", "List"],
      certificate_permissions = ["Backup", "Create", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Import", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Update"]
    }
    ,
   ]

   log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.resource_id
}



Have you checked the permissions are correctly provided for the key vault to access it and also check the logged in user has necessary action permissions to perform the operation. @SVt


Message="The user, group or application 'appid=xxx;oid=xxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/6f/' does not have secrets get permission:

The above issue comes when the user you logged in the current environment doesn't have necessary Getpermissions to get the secret from key vault. You need to set the tenant_id and object_id under access policy in the key vault as shown below.
Refer: data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
azurerm_key_vault
tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

I have tried the same code as you just by adding the above lines worked for me as expected.



